# Create a Wordpress page with custom url and custom code in Themes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

For additional page in my wordpress website I need a URL XYZ.com/ABC

Where ABC is some page-ABC.php file in themes folder. Or something like that.

I just want to print the independent contents from the theme folder. but within the same theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your create a page in the WP admin with slug (permalink) "abc", you can then create a PHP file in your themes dir called "page-abc.php". Then go to the edit screen for your page, under "Page Attributes" you will find the template field where you can select your new custom template to be used when displaying that page.

Comment: Thanks I got the idea. This is what exactly I need.